# Install and use the latest version of Ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am making a script to install the latest stable ruby using rvm. I use:

```
rvm install ruby --latest
```

But the problem is, since I do not know which version is going to be installed, I do not know how to use `rvm use` to set it as the default ruby version.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
rvm use ruby --latest --default
```

Comment: This works great. Little extra question. Do you know how to make the "install" and "use" quietly? less verbose?